# ¿Cómo pasar los valores de un formulario html a un documento .js?

Tags: javascript, formularios

Buenos días,
tengo un formulario realizado en un archivo html y quiero pasar los valores a un archivo .js y operar con ellos. Sé cómo se hace si todo el código está dentro del html, pero no sé hacerlo desde un archivo de javascript independiente.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un archivo `js` no puede operar independiente, este debe ser cargado en conjunto con archivo `html`, ya sabes como operar si ambos (`html` y `js`) están en un mismo archivo, lo que te falta saber es como cargar el archivo `js` si este no esta dentro del código `html`, con el siguiente código lo puedes hacer: `<script src="...nombre del archivo js..."></script>`, coloca este código en la cabecera `<head>` de tu archivo `html`.

Comment: El HTML y el JS deberán estar en el mismo DOM y a través de un botón en HTML llamando a una función en JS, por ejemplo: `<button onclick="miFuncion()">Presioname</button`   y podrás capturar los valores de los inputs a través del ID --> `variabledelfurmulario= document.getElementById('prueba').value` y tomar las acciones que quieras, no te olvides de utilizar el `preventDefault()` para neutralizar la acción del SUBMIT y tomar el control de lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f);

function f(){
 var nombre = document.forms["c"]["nombre"],
     nombreActual = "";
 nombre.addEventListener("keyup", () =>{
     console.log(nombre.value);
 });
     
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form name="c">
Nombre:<input type="text" name="nombre" id="n">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

En el HTML deberías hacer referencia a la ubicación de tu script JS, colocando su src ya sea en el head o en el body, dependiendo de las necesidades de tu aplicación.
Ejemplo:

```
`<html>
    <head>
   </head>
    <body>
        <p id="prueba">Texto</p>
        <script src="./app.js"/>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Luego en tu script app.js:

```
`var parrafo = document.getElementById('prueba');
  console.log('Ejemplo: ', parrafo.value);
 //Debería devolver en la consola: Ejemplo: Texto`
```

En este ejemplo, ambos archivos (index.html y app.js) se encuentran en la misma ubicación.

Answer (score 1):

Yo te lo manejo con jQuery, pero todo lo demas lo tendrias que hacer con php

ejemplo

este seria el HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
            <label for="">Nombre:</label>
            <input type='text' class='from' placeholder="Ejem: StackOverflow" id="nombre_alumn" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
            <label for="">Grupo:</label>
            <input type='text' class='from' placeholder="1°B" id="grupo_alumn">
        </div>
        <input type='button' class='btn btn-dark' value="Registra alumno" id="registra" >
        </div>

    </form>
    <div id="resultado" ></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora este seria el script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#registra').on('click',function(){
       var nombre = $('#nombre_alumn').val();
       var grupo = $('#grupo_alumn').val();
       var datos = {nombre:nombre,
        grupo:grupo
    }
       var json = JSON.stringify(datos);
       $.post("prueba.php",{data:datos},function(){

       }).done(function(data){
        $('#resultado').html(data)
       }).fail(function(error){
        $('#resultado').html(error)
       })
      })

  })
</script>
```

y por ultimo este seria el php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $datos = $_POST['data'];
    $data = json_decode($datos);
    $nombre_alumno = $data->nombre;
    $grupo_alumno = $data->grupo;
    return "registro hecho";
}

?>
```